# Flexible regular expression to take out parts of DOM

Tags: php, regex, pcre

First, I know about Simple HTML Dom parser and PHP's built-in solution, which none of them are doing exactly that kind of job I'm asking for (not to my knowledge).

I'm looking for PHP's PCRE that will find the element and the belonging content inside DOM, delete it and forgive if markup contains any extra whitespace.

Here is code:

```
<div id="maindiv">
    <div class="unusefuldiv1">Unuseful content</div>
    <div id="unusefuldiv2">Unuseful content2</div>
    <!--  ... some content I'm after for -->
</div>
```

I'm desperate about regular expression pattern that will delete both .uunusefuldiv1 and #unusefuldiv2 (markup together with content) and be (if possible) enough flexible to do the job if,
for example `<div class="unusefuldiv1">` is slightly mistyped with extra empty space: `<div class="unusefuldiv1" >` .

That might be something *similar* to

`preg_replace('/<div\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div>/is', '', $dom_content);`

except that this pattern will delete all div's, be them with of some classes, id's or without.

Does anyone have solution?

Comment: "which none of them are doing exactly that kind of job I'm asking for (not to my knowledge)" am I allowed to post an answer proving you wrong?

Comment: Yes please. If you have working example, I'm lucky today. But, my best option is regular expression pattern

Comment: No your best option is not regex. 1 sec let me write up a quick example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dom_content = preg_replace( 
    '/\s*<div [^<>]*unuseful[^<>]+>.*?<\/div\s*>\s*/is', '', $dom_content );
```

will remove divs (and surrounding whitespace) whose opening tag contains the word unuseful.

For a better regex solution you will need to better describe the criteria for deleting a div.

Comment: No, Mike (obviously I didn't made it clear) I need "unuseful" to be any valid css class or id name.

Comment: So why shouldn't `<div id="maindiv">` be deleted? Is the criteria only delete divs inside other divs?

Comment: I'm totally sorry here, this is what I was searching for! Thanks MikeM (I need vacation, this work is killing me)

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to not use a deidcated DOM parser here:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$id = 'unusefuldiv2';
$classname = 'unusefuldiv1';
$query = "//div[@id='$id']|//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]";
foreach ($xpath->query($query) as $node) {    
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Demo: http://eval.in/11108

Comment: This solution works perfectly for this parameters, but I didn't catch solution if I have something additional to one #id and one .class or when there's just one .class for example, and all that since I do not understand $query pattern. Give me PCRE pattern (since obvious you know it) so I could accept your answer with piece in mind (I voted up so far).

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. This example removes all div's with either id `unusefuldiv2` or class `unusefuldiv1` and leaves all other elements untouched. Is this not what you want?